# Angularjs and $locale

Tags: localization, angularjs

Can I set $locale for some application manually?

Is it possible that only way to support locals is to include localization file from angular library for current locale. What if there are multiple cultures? In that case I have to load localization files dynamically? What am I missing?

Comment: See also https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/N5XYOvOPR6I/bMbUpifQpuYJ

Comment: One more link: http://codingsmackdown.tv/blog/2012/12/14/localizing-your-angularjs-app/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Honestly, the $locale service in angular is pretty primitive still. It's really good, but it seems to lack flexibility in this area. The biggest issue is that even if you switch your locale by dynamically reloading the proper locale file, things like the date filter won't know you've changed it because they're registering their locale information when they're set up. So you have a couple of choices currently: 1. Reload the page with the selected locale... or 2. Write your own Locale Provider and Filters that use it.

It *might* be possible create a service that would dynamically load the proper script file, reinitialize all affected filters and services, then refresh the views, but I'm not really sure what all that would involve at this point.

Comment: Thanks,I like control so I am going to write my own custom Locale Provider.

Comment: You could probably have your LocaleProvider match the signature of the original one, but have JavaScript property setters and getters on each item in the locale to allow you to programmatically check whatever locale you need to.

Comment: I've written a custom locale provider but it only takes effect on date filters, both number and currency capture their formats in a closure.

Comment: @MariusSoutier is that custom locale provider something you can share?  I am looking at this same problem

Answer (score 32):

You can load the locale you want into `localStorage`, then refresh the page. Have the script below load the i18n file you need. Changing the locale on the fly isn't supported yet.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var locale = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('locale'));
if (locale) {
    document.write('<script src="scripts/i18n/angular-locale_'+locale+'.js"><\/script>');
}
</script>
```

Comment: This worked for me. I did have to change "angular-locale_" to "angular-locale\\_", though (escaping the underscore).

Comment: Worked like a charm, no server side code required, well accepted by angular. This is a really time saving solution!

Comment: This worked for me. I was struggling with all other options for a long time.

Comment: This fix requires refresh of the page. For first load of the page you can simply get browser language through window.navigator object as a fallback.

Answer (score 31):

I've built an angular module that takes care about i18n. AngularJS support for i18n is pretty primitve, if you want to have more control and also be more flexible, checkout angular-translate - http://angular-translate.github.io/

Let me know, if I can help out!

Comment: How does it handle dates?

Comment: It actually doesn't handle dates at all. angular-translate is all about translating contents (not dates specifically), with support for asynchronous loading and proper pluralization.

Comment: I use moment.js with angular-translate to handle dates

Comment: `$locale` is not the `i18n` part of the thing, `$locale` is the `i10n`

Answer (score 24):

For anyone looking for dynamic localization today [angular-dynamic-locale](https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale) does a great job.

Answer (score 23):

I struggled with the same issues, read all the answers here and introduced i18n/l10n in my project. This are my outcomes:

- angular-translate (http://angular-translate.github.io) is a perfect way to localize your **content** (custom-strings). But it does **NOT** translate angular's date, currency or number-filters.
- Angular has a built-in mechanism to localize **date, currency or number**-filters. Translations for supported locales can be found here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ngLocale, the angular-guide is located at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n
- The problem with angular's built-in mechanism: it's not that easy to **change the locale at run time**! This is where https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale comes into play. It allows you to change the language at run time pretty easily.

So the solution is to use both projects, *angular-translate* and *angular-dynamic-locale*.

Comment: When i try this approach I am getting $translateProvider.useUrlLoader is not a function

Answer (score 2):

Including this script: https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale/blob/master/src/tmhDynamicLocale.js enables locales to be set during run time.

1. Download all the locales you want from https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ngLocale
2. Store the locales in a directory on your web server, e.g. `/assets/js/locales/filename-LOCALE.js` - *note: what you write as the* **LOCALE** *in the filename is important* - any locales required will get downloaded dynamically.
3. In your module, include `tmhDynamicLocale` as `'tmh.DynamicLocale'` e.g. `var app = angular.module('app',['tmh.DynamicLocale'])`;
4. In your config, pass in the provider i.e. '`tmhDynamicLocaleProvider`' and set the location of your locale files, e.g. `tmhLocaleProvider.localeLocationPattern('/assets/js/locales/angular-locale-{{locale}}.js');` `{{locale}}` will be swapped out for the locale you set at run time.
5. To set the locale across your app, in `app.run()`, pass in the `'tmhDynamicLocale'` service e.g. `app.run(['tmhDynamicLocale',function(tmhDynamicLocale){}]);`
6. In your run callback, set the locale like this, `tmhDynamicLocale.set('en-gb');`. Alternatvely, as `tmhDynamicLocale` is a service, you could set the locale in different places service injections are allowed, e.g. controllers, although bear in mind, services are singletons, and setting the locale in a controller will set it across the app.

You should now have the correct locale running. For further info, use the *README* for `tmhDynamicLocale`:https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale/blob/master/README.md

Credit: [Lucas Mirelmann](https://github.com/lgalfaso)  for `tmhDynamicLocale`.

Comment: When i try this approach I am getting $translateProvider.useUrlLoader is not a function

Comment: @MiomirDancevic Your error doesn't sound related to using this module.

Answer (score 1):

I found something interesting. It is not angular but it is jquery so integration should be ok.
I will test performances and get back with info.

https://github.com/js-coder/x18n/wiki/Getting-started

https://github.com/js-coder/jQuery.x18n

Comment: I found it complex to implement so I finished with simple service that loads resources from server and caches it. For translation to be shown  I used simple directive.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load the angularJS localization of your browser, install https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-i18n and https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale in your project.

Read the documentation of each library to install. This is an example of my Ionic project:

1. In my index.html:

   ```
   ...
   <!-- angular-dynamic-locale-->
   <script src="lib/angular-dynamic-locale/tmhDynamicLocale.min.js"></script>
   ...
   ```
2. In my app.js

   ```
   var app = angular.module('project-name', ['ionic',..., 'tmh.dynamicLocale']);
   ...
   // tmhDynamicLocaleProvider
   app.config(function(tmhDynamicLocaleProvider) {
      //  override the default path (angular/i18n/angular-locale_{{locale}}.js) to the stored Angular i18n locale files
      tmhDynamicLocaleProvider.localeLocationPattern('lib/angular-i18n/angular-locale_{{locale}}.js');
   })
   ...
   app.run(function($rootScope, $ionicPlatform, ..., tmhDynamicLocale){
      // set locale for angular formats   
      var inArray = function(needle, haystack) {
         var key = '';
         for (key in haystack) {
            if (haystack[key] === needle) {
               return true;
            }
         }
         return false;
      };
      var preferredLanguage = navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage || navigator.systemLanguage || navigator.userLanguage;
      if (typeof preferredLanguage === 'string') {
         var code = preferredLanguage.substring(2, 0);
            if (inArray(code, PROPERTIES.LANGUAGES)) {
               tmhDynamicLocale.set(code);
            }
      }
      ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Angular provide great support for  i18n/l10n.
You can find the guide [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n)

The requirements for our application determines how we can implement this support.

1. If our application requires only a single locale or the end users of our application belongs only to a particular locale then we can restrict our application scope for  i18n/l10n to only that  locale

You can find a good explanation of how we can achieve such things in one of my previous answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547680/angular-js-currency-symbol-euro-after/#answer-47881020).

2. If we want to serve a particular component, directive or part to display in some other format or locale then we can go for some directives components or even a filter for that

You can find an example fiddle for such implementation using a filter can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/samuelj90/ADukg/16945/)

```
 function MyController($scope) {
   $scope.property = {
     price: 50000000.557
   }
 }

 function toLocaleCurrencyFilter($filter) {
  return function(amount, currencySymbol, fractionSize, locale) {
    var returnValue = Number(parseFloat(amount)).toLocaleString(locale, {
      minimumFractionDigits: parseInt(fractionSize),
      maximumFractionDigits: parseInt(fractionSize),
    });
    returnValue = returnValue + " " + currencySymbol
    return returnValue;
  };
 }
 angular.module('myApp', [])
   .controller('MyController', ['$scope', MyController])
   .filter('toLocaleCurrency', ['$filter', toLocaleCurrencyFilter]);
```

3. If we want dynamic locale then you need to reload browser with the new locale settings by saving it into local storage to take effect.
   you can use the solution described in 1 with some dynamic nature.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webpack and typescript, you can load your locale dynamically.

```
    export const loadLocale = function(lng){
    if(lng != 'en'){
        require('./angular-locale_' + lng + '.js');
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also use the translation service to get the browser's locale then use it to do what you need. . . for example, in a ShortDatePipe:

```
   import { Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
    import { formatDate  } from '@angular/common';
    import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

    @Pipe({
      name: 'shortDate'
    })
    export class ShortDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
        constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) { }

        transform(value: string): string {
            var language: string = this.translateService.getBrowserCultureLang();
            console.log(language);
            return (value == "" || value == null) ? "" : formatDate(value, 'shortDate', language);
        }

    }
```

Comment: That looks like angular code but not angularjs code.

Comment: yea sorry, it's not angularjs, it's like v 8