# Force a locale in angular i18n

Tags: angularjs, internationalization

I would like to force a language for [angular i18n](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n).

Currently it's using the browser locale, but I would like to be able to force another language (in the case the user account language is set to English and the browser is in Spanish, for example).

I tried injecting `$locale` in my main controller and doing `$locale.id = 'en-us'` but it doesn't change anything. I expect the `date`, `number` and `currency` filters to change output format, but nothing.

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs and $locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007430/angularjs-and-locale)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered here:

[Angularjs and $locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007430/angularjs-and-locale)

It seems you need to only include the relevant language file.