# Angular Dynamic Locale not working instantly

Tags: angularjs, localization, datepicker, locale, angular-ui-bootstrap

I use [angular-dynamic-locale](https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale/) to change the language of [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)'s datepicker (I do not want to add the right localization source file at the server side. Hence, I need something more dynamic).

The localization file is loaded. However, when I open a datepicker on my page, the localization takes place only after I switch to a new month via the `<`, `>` buttons.

Is there any way to have this change happen directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never mind, I actually found a solution which does not involve dynamic localization. As [proposed by will Farrrell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007430/angularjs-and-locale), I detect the user's locale right in the header of my `index.html` and load the according locale:

```
var locale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
if (locale) {
    var smallLocale = locale.toLowerCase();
    document.write('<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.2.15/angular-locale_' + smallLocale + '.js"><\/script>');
}
```

This works for the datepicker (if dynamic behaviour is not needed).